# How do I choose specific files in a different directory using bash?

Tags: bash, directory, regular-expression, wildcards

I want to list (or delete, or do some other operation) on certain files in a directory, like this:

```
$ ls /opt/somedir/
aa  bb  cc  aa.txt  bb.txt  cc.txt
$ ls /opt/somedir/(aa|bb|cc)  ## pseudo-bash :p
aa  bb  cc
```

How can I achieve this (without cd-ing to the directory first)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use curly braces for it:

```
ls /opt/somedir/{aa,bb,cc}
```

For more information read about [brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion).

Answer (score 3):

Under bash, run `shopt -s extglob` (or put it in your `~/.bashrc`), and you can use additional [patterns](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) that provide regular expressions with an unusual syntax (inherited from ksh). You can use these patterns in ksh too, of course, and also in zsh after `setopt ksh_glob`.

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ ls /opt/somedir/@(aa|bb|cc|doesnotexist)
/opt/somedir/aa   /opt/somedir/bb  /opt/somedir/cc
```

In zsh, you can directly use `(foo|bar)` as a pattern.

```
% ls /opt/somedir/(aa|bb|cc|doesnotexist)
/opt/somedir/aa   /opt/somedir/bb  /opt/somedir/cc
```

Note that the command is called with the full path. If you want to call the command with a short path, you'll need to change the directory somehow, and `(cd /opt/somedir && somecommand aa bb cc)` is by far the easiest way.

Comment: If you look closely, you'll see that I specify "without cd-ing to the directory first" in my question ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can filter using `egrep`:

```
ls | egrep '(aa|bb|cc)'
```

To find all text files:

```
ls | egrep '(aa|bb|cc).txt'
```

Comment: dot will match every character, and this approach make it difficult to further operate on these files

Comment: I got the feeling that ls was just an example command, too.

Comment: Yup, you're right, I specified that I want to do perform an operation: listing files was just an example.

Comment: Good comments dear friends, thanks. Good luck neu242 :D

Answer (score 1):

First, I direct you to: [never parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), *ever*. The proper, and canonical way to do what you want is with [find](http://ss64.com/bash/find.html).

For example:

```
find /opt/somedir -regex '.*[aa|bb|cc].*' -exec mv '{}' ~/backup \;
```

I usually use `-name` instead of `-regex` as it is simpler. But a regex fits your use case. You should run the command *without* `-exec` the first time, to make sure they actually are the files you want moved/deleted.

Comment: I never said I'd parse ls, and Rush had a far better answer.  Thanks for trying, though :)